# How to upload large zip file to PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, file-upload, browser, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Our app is now a large zip file. It's **+800 MB**. But since we have the [Adobe Creative Cloud Membership](https://build.phonegap.com/plans) that allow an app size of up to 1 GB, this shouldn't be any problem.

But there is; We can't upload this large zip file to [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com). The browser gets timeout and dies after 2,5 min. And the problem is that it seems not possible to change the timeout in either Chrome or Safari. Have tried to [change it in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/sv/questions/1042479) but it doesn't have any affect.

Is there any other way to upload the zip file? Except Github. Is there any way to do it for example with command line? Or any other tricks to fix browsers load timeout time?

Comment: Well you could simply use Cordova locally...

Comment: Don't know if I agree with "simply", but after a few hours I'm starting to get the hang of it... :)

Comment: Peter, this is the way to go and you won't look back! Good luck.